# What does mean '#' in Vue Router URL?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am curious what does mean the hash in Vue Router URL? I see that I can use `mode: 'history'` to remove it, but what is the effective difference using it and not use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue uses the hash to stop the page from being reloaded whenever the URL changes. History mode removes this feature, but there are some configurations you need to consider.

Info: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html